# AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I am trying to make a simple music player but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/nickw/PycharmProjects/untitled1/music player", line 28, in <module>
        slider = tk.Scale(window, from_=100, to=0, command=setVolume)
      File "C:\Users\nickw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2856, in __init__
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'scale', cnf, kw)
      File "C:\Users\nickw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2132, in __init__
        BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
      File "C:\Users\nickw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2110, in _setup
        self.tk = master.tk
    AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tk'
```

This is my code:

```
import pygame
import Tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music")

started = False
playing = False

def buttonClick():
    global playing, started
    if not playing:
        if not started:
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
            started=True
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        button.config(text ="Pause")
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        button.config(text="play")
        playing = not playing
def setVolume(val):
    volume = float(slider.get())
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume /100)


slider = tk.Scale(window, text="play", command="buttonClick")
button = tk.Button(tk, text = "play", command = buttonClick)

slider.pack()
slider.set(100)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cannot find the error line `slider = tk.Scale(window, from_=100, to=0, command=setVolume)` in your code (seems like this line `slider = tk.Scale(window, text="play", command="buttonClick")` in your code.  Another problem is that in the error messages, you are using Python 3, but you use `Tkinter` in your code.  It should be `tkinter`.  Post your real code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using python 3.x you have to change your `import`-line from

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

to

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Another problem is your `slider`: the constructor expects a function as last argument, you give it a string. You actually know the correct way, as I can see on the following line.

Answer (score 5):

I actually found the error! There was many so the `tkinter` problem was solved with

```
from tkinter import *
tk=Tk()
```

and the scale problem I corrected with this line.

```
w = Scale(tk, from_=0, to=100, command=setVolume)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have named your python file name as `tkinter.py` or `Tkinter.py`, change the file name to something else, it will get rid of the `attribute error`