# AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, attributeerror

I am trying to make a simple menu (at the moment) but I keep getting this error:

```
 class pyFinanceStart(tk.Tk):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

         container = tk.Frame(self)
         container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
         container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
         container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

         self.frames = {}

         for F in (StartPage):

             frame = F(container, self)
             self.frames[F] = frame
             frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

             self.show_frame(StartPage)

     def show_frame(self, cont):
         frame = self.frames[cont]
         frame.tkraise()


 class StartPage(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)                
          container = tk.Frame(self)
          container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
          container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
          container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

          menubar = tk.Menu(container)        
          topIndi = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=1)
          topIndi.add_command(label="None")#,command=lambda: addTopIndicator('none'))
          topIndi.add_separator()
          topIndi.add_command ( label="RSI")#,command=lambda: addTopIndicator('rsi'))
          topIndi.add_command ( label="MACD")#,command=lambda: addTopIndicator('macd'))
          menubar.add_cascade(label = "Top Indicator", menu = topIndi)

          helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
          helpmenu.add_command(label="Help")
          menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

          tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)
```

I have the error: AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'config'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tk'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480367/attributeerror-module-tkinter-has-no-attribute-tk)

Comment: not i´m using python 3.x

Comment: Please post the stacktrace, and any other information that could help in debugging the issue.

Comment: You need to include enough code in your question to allow others to reproduce the problem. Please [edit] it and do so. When I try to run your code as currently posted, I get a different error on the `tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)` line—which is indeed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error reported in my Windows box with Python 3.7.1 is not the same as yours.  Mine is `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"`.  It is because `menu` option is supported by toplevel containers only, not for `Frame` widget.

Below is modified code based on yours which fixes the error:

```
import tkinter as tk

class pyFinanceStart(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.geometry("300x100")
    # make the frame using all the window area
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    # create the pages
    self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage,):
      frame = F(self)
      frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
      self.frames[F] = frame
    # show the start page
    self.show_frame(StartPage)

  def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='blue')
    tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", bg='#ffc').pack(fill='both', expand=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    # create the menubar
    menubar = tk.Menu(parent)
    # create the 'Top Indicator' menu
    topIndi = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=1)
    topIndi.add_command(label="None")
    topIndi.add_separator()
    topIndi.add_command(label="RSI")
    topIndi.add_command(label="MACD")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Top Indicator", menu=topIndi)
    # create the 'Help' menu
    helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="Help")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
    # set the toplevel menubar
    parent.config(menu=menubar) # or tk.Tk.config(parent, menu=menubar)

pyFinanceStart().mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]